# How to find the disk usage ONLY of 2nd level dirs?

Tags: linux, command-line, disk-usage

I have the following dir structure:

```
relative_path/
              app1/
                   data
                   config
                   trash
              other_app/
                        inputs
                        outputs
                        garbage
              anything_else/
                            v1/
                               v1.5
                            v2/
```

I need to figure out the disk usage of each dir only on the second level (e.g. `relative_path/anything_else/v1`, but not `relative_path/anything_else` nor `relative_path/anything_else/v1/v1.5`)

If I do a `du -d2 relative_path` it won't list the dirs on 3rd+ levels, but will still list the 1st-level dir.

How can I filter out **ONLY** 2nd level dirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the directories of the target depth with GNU `find` or a shell loop, use
`-s` (same as `-d0`) to display a total for each argument. This would
output `relative_path/anything_else/v1` but show the total for this dir and its subdirectories.

If you also want to exclude the sizes of subdirectories, add another `-S`.

```
find relative_path -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec du -sS {} \;
```

or

```
for dir in relative_path/*/*/; do
    du -sS "$dir"
done
```